# Assert exception from NUnit to MS TEST

Tags: nunit, mstest

I have some tests where i am checking for parameter name in exception.
How do i write this in MS TEST?

```cs
ArgumentNullException exception = 
              Assert.Throws<ArgumentNullException>(
                            () => new NHibernateLawbaseCaseDataLoader( 
                                               null, 
                                               _mockExRepository,
                                               _mockBenRepository));

Assert.AreEqual("lawbaseFixedContactRepository", exception.ParamName);
```

I have been hoping for neater way so i can avoid using try catch block in the tests.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```cs
public static class ExceptionAssert
{
  public static T Throws<T>(Action action) where T : Exception
  {
    try
    {
      action();
    }
    catch (T ex)
    {
      return ex;
    }

    Assert.Fail("Expected exception of type {0}.", typeof(T));

    return null;
  }
}
```

You can use the extension method above as a test helper. Here is an example of how to  use it:

```cs
// test method
var exception = ExceptionAssert.Throws<ArgumentNullException>(
              () => organizations.GetOrganization());
Assert.AreEqual("lawbaseFixedContactRepository", exception.ParamName);
```

Comment: in your second code block wouldn't it be more correct to check for exception != null?

Comment: You can add another catch block for the rest of the exceptions and say, "Expected exception was abc but got xyz".

Answer (score 7):

Shameless plug, but I wrote a simple assembly that makes asserting exceptions and exception messages a little easier and more readable in MSTest using *Assert.Throws()* syntax in the style of nUnit/xUnit.

You can download the package from Nuget using: **PM> Install-Package MSTestExtensions**

Or you can see the full source code here: https://github.com/bbraithwaite/MSTestExtensions

High level instructions, download the assembly and inherit from *BaseTest* and you can use the *Assert.Throws()* syntax.

The main method for the Throws implementation looks as follows:

```
public static void Throws<T>(Action task, string expectedMessage, ExceptionMessageCompareOptions options) where T : Exception
{
    try
    {
        task();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        AssertExceptionType<T>(ex);
        AssertExceptionMessage(ex, expectedMessage, options);
        return;
    }

    if (typeof(T).Equals(new Exception().GetType()))
    {
        Assert.Fail("Expected exception but no exception was thrown.");
    }
    else
    {
        Assert.Fail(string.Format("Expected exception of type {0} but no exception was thrown.", typeof(T)));
    }
}
```

More info [here](http://www.bradoncode.com/blog/2012/01/asserting-exceptions-in-mstest-with.html).

Comment: I have none to give, but I appreciate yours! I hope you didn't take offense at my comment. While my expertise on SO lies in entirely different subject areas, I try to give back to the site by editing when I can and encouraging folks like you to post higher quality answers. It all adds up to a site that's a much more valuable resource to others.

Answer (score 3):

Since the MSTest `[ExpectedException]` attribute doesn't check the text in the message, your best bet is to try...catch and set an Assert on the exception Message / ParamName property.