# unit testing an exception thrown in a controller

Tags: c#, unit-testing, exception, asp.net-mvc-4

I am currently unit testing that when invalid form collection data is sent that an error is thrown.

The exception is thrown within a HttpPost Index ActionResult method which is shown below:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Index(FormCollection formCollection, PaymentType payType, string progCode)
    {
        ActionResult ar = redirectFromButtonData(formCollection, payType, progCode);

        if (ar != null)
        {
            return ar;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Cannot redirect to payment form from cohort decision - Type:[" +  payType.ToString()  + "] Prog:[" +  Microsoft.Security.Application.Encoder.HtmlEncode(progCode) + "]");
        }
    }
```

so far I have written a test that successfully hits the exception (I have verified this by enabling code coverage which I have being using to see what code is being executed by each individual test) but currently the test fails because I have not as yet defined a way of testing that the exception has been thrown, the code for this test can be found below:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Error_Is_Thrown_If_HVM_FormCollection_Data_Is_Incorrect()
    {
        var formCollection = new FormCollection();
        formCollection.Add("__RequestVerificationToken", "__RequestVerificationToken");
        formCollection.Add("invalid - invalid", "invalid- invalid");


        var payType = new PaymentType();
        payType = PaymentType.deposit;

        var progCode = "hvm";

        var mocks = new MockRepository();

        var httpRequest = mocks.DynamicMock<HttpRequestBase>();
        var httpContext = mocks.DynamicMock<HttpContextBase>();
        controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(httpContext, new RouteData(), controller);
        mocks.ReplayAll();

        httpRequest.Expect(r => r.Url).Return(new Uri("http://localhost:8080/hvm/full/self/")).Repeat.Any();

        httpContext.Expect(c => c.Request).Return(httpRequest).Repeat.Any();

        var result = controller.Index(formCollection, payType, progCode);
    }
```

I have looked at using `[ExpectedException(typeof(Exception)]` annotation could this be used in this case?

Comment: heya, which version of rhinomocks are you using?

Comment: hmm, and `ExpectedException` could be buggy with MStest. Nunit supports it better. Is there a reason for MStest or can you switch to Nunit without a problem?

Comment: Ah, then you can also write mocks easier, without instantiating a mockrepository, I'll post something in a bit.

Comment: I'm using MSTest so that I can run the tests on TFS 2010, as far as I am aware of nunit tests cannot, may well be wrong with that assumption

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213569/assert-exception-from-nunit-to-ms-test

Comment: ah that I can't say for sure. It'd surprise me if TFS would not run with Nunit, but that I can't say for sure. I bet google knows :).

Comment: by the looks of it can be done with some configuration, the problem is I have already written quite a lot of tests it's a fairly substantial application that I'm testing, plus I made the mistake of unit testing after the application had been created rather than using TDD

Comment: Ah yeah I hear your. I also rewrote a test framework from MStest to Nunit once. It was fairly straight forward. But I understand that you have better things to do then taking the hit now. Anyway, googled a bit more and a lot of complaints about `ExpectedException` in MStest. It seems broken

Comment: Try Fluent Assertions project.. you can use something like: controller.Invoking(c => c.Index(formCollection, payType, progCode)).ShouldThrow<Exception>(); Has the advantage that you can pin the exception down to a very specific line rather than an entire unit test as is the case with the [ExpectedException] decoration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took the liberty of changing your test code slightly conform latest features of rhino-mocks. It;s no longer required to create `MockRepository`, you can use the static class `MockRepository` and call `GenerateMock<>`. I also moved your SuT (system under test) instantiation **below** the specification for you mocks.

Example with Nunit (I have better experiences with Nunit than with MSTest. Mostly because Nunit releases more often and have more reliable feature sets. Again, not sure if it works with TFS but that should not be that hard to find out).

```
[Test] // Nunit
[ExpectedException(typeof(Exception)) // NOTE: it's wise to throw specific 
// exceptions so that you prevent false-positives! (another "exception" 
// might make the test pass while it's a completely different scenario)
public void Error_Is_Thrown_If_HVM_FormCollection_Data_Is_Incorrect()
{
    var formCollection = new FormCollection();
    formCollection.Add("__RequestVerificationToken", "__RequestVerificationToken");
    formCollection.Add("invalid - invalid", "invalid- invalid");

    var payType = new PaymentType();
    payType = PaymentType.deposit;

    var progCode = "hvm";

    var httpRequest = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpRequestBase>();
    var httpContext = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpContextBase>();

    // define behaviour
    httpRequest.Expect(r => r.Url).Return(new Uri("http://localhost:8080/hvm/full/self/")).Repeat.Any();
    httpContext.Expect(c => c.Request).Return(httpRequest).Repeat.Any();

    // instantiate SuT (system under test)
    controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(httpContext, new RouteData(), controller);

    // Test the stuff, and if nothing is thrown then the test fails
    var result = controller.Index(formCollection, payType, progCode);
}
```

And pretty much the same deal with MStest, except that you need to define the expected exception a bit more oldskool.

```
[TestMethod] // MStest
public void Error_Is_Thrown_If_HVM_FormCollection_Data_Is_Incorrect()
{
    try
    {
        var formCollection = new FormCollection();
        formCollection.Add("__RequestVerificationToken", "__RequestVerificationToken");
        formCollection.Add("invalid - invalid", "invalid- invalid");

        var payType = new PaymentType();
        payType = PaymentType.deposit;

        var progCode = "hvm";

        var httpRequest = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpRequestBase>();
        var httpContext = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpContextBase>();

        // define behaviour
        httpRequest.Expect(r => r.Url).Return(new Uri("http://localhost:8080/hvm/full/self/")).Repeat.Any();
        httpContext.Expect(c => c.Request).Return(httpRequest).Repeat.Any();

        // instantiate SuT (system under test)
        controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(httpContext, new RouteData(), controller);

        // Test the stuff, and if nothing is thrown then the test fails
        var result = controller.Index(formCollection, payType, progCode);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Assert.Pass();
    }
    Assert.Fail("Expected exception Exception, was not thrown");
}
```

If you got that part working, you could refactor it for better re-usability via the link provided: [Assert exception from NUnit to MS TEST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213569/assert-exception-from-nunit-to-ms-test).

Comment: For the `MsTest` test, it might be clearer to only have the call that could throw the exception within the try block?

Comment: for the next iteration of the project I am going to be doing a large amount of refactoring so will probably look at moving to NUnit anyway, I was planning on making a number of changes to the way errors are handled probably using redirects so that it forward to a custom error view rather than throwing an exception. I have two other project based on MVC 4 that use this approach and its much easier to test

Comment: For me, it says there is no `Assert.Pass()` for **MSTest**!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to test this would be to wrap the call in a try-catch and set a boolean variable if the catch block is executed. Something like:

```
var exceptionIsThrown = false;
ActionResult result;
try 
{
    result = controller.Index(formCollection, payType, progCode);
}
catch(Exception)
{
    exceptionIsThrown = true;
}
```